# Oracle Cloud Infrastructure - Let group admins manage group membership

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Did someone manage to make this suggested policy "Let group admins manage group membership" work?

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Identity/Concepts/commonpolicies.htm#group-admins-manage-group-membership

```
Allow group GroupAdmins to inspect users in tenancy

Allow group GroupAdmins to inspect groups in tenancy

Allow group GroupAdmins to use users in tenancy where target.group.name != 'Administrators'

Allow group GroupAdmins to use groups in tenancy where target.group.name != 'Administrators'
```

Comment: For clarity, are you saying the documentation as written is incorrect, or that you can not successfully implement this policy?

Comment: I failed to run this policy at my tenancy which suggests me that maybe documentation is incorrect at that point. Maybe someone else was able to make it work, in that case it means that's not docs issue. btw. I hope it's something wrong with backend etc and docs are right because this feature would be very useful. 

Unfortunately i found also docs which describe this feature as not available, which means that we got inconsistent docs/ui/console

Comment: Can you elaborate with what the error you received is, or what didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about the error you are receiving, we won't be able to help resolve/answer. Please note that if you are trying to use the `use groups` permission without also using 'use users` it won't work as user group membership updates set the target group.